# Adjuntar PDF en correo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tengo dudas sobre como adjuntar un PDF, tengo un servicio que envía correos, pero lo que ahora tengo que hacer es generar un PDF y adjuntarlo al correo, pero no necesito descargarlo ya que mi método que envía el correo se ejecuta al hacer una acción. Por ejemplo, cuando le doy clic a un botón se ejecuta el método y se dispara el correo, y el segundo paso que quiero hacer es, darle clic a ese botón, se ejecuta el método, se adjunta el PDF y se dispara el correo ya con el PDF adjunto.
Quiero saber si eso es posible.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este aproximarse:

```
public static void SendMailByTemplate(string to, string subject, string body, 
   string customer, Attachment[] attachments = null)
{
    try
    {    
        var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;   using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(root + @"/Templates/MyEmailTemplate.txt"))
        {
            string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string StrContent = string.Empty;
            StrContent = readFile;

            //Here replace the name with [MyName]
            StrContent = StrContent.Replace("[CustomerName]", customer);

            //... you can add extra parameters here and set them as "CustomerName"
            body = StrContent.ToString();
        }
 
        using (var client = new SmtpClient("0.0.0.0")
        {
            Port = 000,
            Timeout = 9999999,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myaccount@abc.com", "mypassword")
        })
 
        using (var mail = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress("sender@abc.com", "Test Message"),
            //From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"]);          
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Priority = MailPriority.Normal,
            DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure,
        })
        {
            if (attachments != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in attachments)
                {
                    mail.Attachments.Add(item);
                }
            }
 
            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.ReplyToList.Add("noreply@abc.com");
            mail.Bcc.Add("bcc@abc.com");
            client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

***MyEmailTemplate.txt:***

```
<!doctype html>
 
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
 
<body>
  <p>Dear [CustomerName]</p>
  <p>Thanks for your subscription</p>
</body>
</html>
```

***Attachment:***

```
// Process open file dialog box results 
if (beAttachment.Value != null)
{
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(dialog.Value);
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```